# How can I merge two SQL report builder conditions for changing background color?

Tags: report, reportbuilder

I have 2 condition for changing my report background in SQL report builder both of this conditions work great separately but when I merge them don't work

First Condition is:

```
IIF(Fields!IsNidCategory_Join.Value=0,IIf(RowNumber("Tablix2")  mod 2=0,"WhiteSmoke","White"),"Yellow"
```

second condition is:

```
IIf(
        InStr(",1098,3649,1927,3748,712,3758,2360,3759,16180,6670,16210,56070,16280,6360,8919,14943,27950,27955,27400,23985,1715,3559,3830,60939,", "," & Fields!NidCategory.Value & ",") > 0,
        "Red",Nothing))
```

please tell me how can I use this two condition together